# Action Script 3.0. How to add random child and items inside with random positions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random, position, addchild

In my flash game are 9 possible rooms. In each room are 3 fixed positions where items can be added. There also are 3 items on every room, but items should be added always in different positions.

For example If here are 3 positions(locations): `A(x=1;y=1)` `B(x=2;y=2)` `C(x=3;y=3)` and `Item1` `Item2` `Item3`, sometimes `Item1` should be added to `A(x=1;y=1)`, sometimes to `B(x=2;y=2)` and etc. should be random chance in which positions items will be added.

---

In this image is shown only 3 rooms, but total I have 9. As you see all rooms have different position for items, but It's fixed on every room and items (blue, pink, yellow) should have ability to change positions everytime It's added to stage.

[image: random rooms]

What will be best performance to do It?

It is declared in following:

```
var room1:Room1 = new Room1();
var item1:Item1 = new Item1();
var item2:Item2 = new Item2();
var item3:Item3 = new Item3();

var room2:Room2 = new Room2();
var item4:Item4 = new Item4();
var item5:Item5 = new Item5();
var item6:Item6 = new Item6();

....
```

So in `Room1` should be added `Item1` `Item2` and `Item3`, in `Room2` should be added `Item4` `Item5` and `Item6` and etc.

First of all I need to choose randomly 1 of 9 rooms. Should It be something like this?

`addChild(Room+randNumber)`

Later I need to specify `if` for every room?

```
if(Room+randNumber == Room1) {
   addChild(Item1);
   addChild(Item2);
   addChild(Item3);
}
```

But in this case how to set 3 static x, y position for every room and set It for every item randomly?

Answer (score 0):

To randomly choose 1 room of 9 use this code:

```
var roomID:int = Math.round(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var room:MovieClip = this["room" + roomID];
addChild(room);
```

The `roomID` is a random number from 1 to 9.
The `room` is a link to the Room1, Room2, ... Room9.

```
if (room is Room1) // or if (roomID == 1)
{
    addChild(item1);
    addChild(item2);
    addChild(item3);
}
```

Next. Let's set x and y position. Where do you store x and y position?
You said: “For example If here are 3 positions(locations): A(x=1;y=1) B(x=2;y=2) C(x=3;y=3)”. What is A, B, C? Instances of the Point class?

Call my function when you will add three items to the stage.

```
    ...
    addChild(item1);
    addChild(item2);
    addChild(item3);

    var A:Point = new Point(100, 100);
    var B:Point = new Point(200, 200);
    var C:Point = new Point(300, 300);

    placeItems([item1, item2, item3], [A, B, C]);
}

function placeItems(items:Array, points:Array)
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        var id:int = Math.round(Math.random() * (points.length - 1));
        items[i].x = points[id].x;
        items[i].y = points[id].y;
        points.splice(id, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for great answer. `A B C` is nothing, I've just used It to explain that I need to have 3 positions.

Comment: I will try It a bit later and will tell you If that worked for me.